# antisymmetric proof clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, relations, binary

i understand antisymmetric proof but i have a problem with an exercise.
there 's a relation $xRy <==> x^2 <= y^2$

i have to check if it is antisymmetric or not over $Z$.

well of course when x and y are squared they will remain positive so even over $Z$, so $x^2$ and $y^2$ positive so if $x^2<=y^2$and $y^2<=x^2$ then $x^2 = y^2$

my problem is that i am confused wether if the proof is

$x^2<=y^2$and $y^2<=x^2$ then $x^2 = y^2$

or

$x^2<=y^2$and $y^2<=x^2$ then $x = y$

because the question is asked on $N$ and $Z$ so if it's the first, it will be antisymmetric on both $N$ and $Z$ and if it's the second, it won't be antisymmetric on $Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undisputably,

$$x^2\le y^2\land x^2\ge y^2\implies x^2=y^2.$$

(Just because $a\le b\land a\ge b\implies a=b$.)

Then

$$x^2=y^2\iff x=\pm y.$$

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!
Over the integers, you have $2R(-2)$ and $(-2)R2$ since $(-2)^2=2^2$. But $2\ne -2$.

Comment: thank you. so i should use the second proof line?i was just confused if i use x=y or x^2 = y^2 at the end.

Comment: Yves gave the right answer.